# Handling method validation exceptions

Tags: ejb-3.1, bean-validation

i did not find any answer for question "How to handle method validation exceptions?", which is thrown automatically by Bean Validation 1.1.

I have following environment:

```
Glassfish 4
hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar (in ear)
```

Now I try to implement auto validation of method parameters:

```
@Local
@ValidateOnExecution(type = ExecutableType.ALL)
public interface SomeServiceLocal {

     String someMethod(@Size(max = 1) String value);

}
```

in execution of:

```
@Stateless
public class OtherBean implements OtherBeanLocal {

   @EJB
   private SomeServiceLocal someService;

   @Override
   public String otherMethod() {
      return someService.someMethod("abc");
   }

}
```

}

Now, when I call otherMethod a receive:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2279)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2060)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
```

followed by

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: 1 constraint violation(s) occurred during method validation
...

Constraint violations: 
 (1) Kind: PARAMETER
 parameter index: 3
 message: size must be between 0 and 1
```

What is a best practice to handle violation exceptions?

Comment: I would assume that depends on your use-case? For example if the input comes from a user via an UI, you probably want to process the ConstraintViolations contained in the ConstraintViolationException and pass the information up to the user. Or if you are doing batch processing you would log the exception and mark the record for inspection, etc

Answer (score 0):

I've created cdi interceptor which handles EJBException and extract constraint violations. It works perfect:

```
@MyValidation
@Interceptor
public class MyValidationExceptionInterceptor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5280505156146359055L;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object processViolationException(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
       try {
          return ctx.proceed();
       } catch (EJBTransactionRolledbackException e) {
          Throwable throwable = e.getCause();
          if (throwable != null && throwable.getCause() != null && throwable.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
             ConstraintViolationException cve = (ConstraintViolationException) throwable.getCause();
             throw new MyException(getMessage(cve));
          }
        throw e;
       } catch (Exception e) {
          throw e;
       }
    }

    private String getMessage(ConstraintViolationException cve) {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       for(ConstraintViolation<?> violation : cve.getConstraintViolations()) {
           builder.append(violation.getMessage()).append(';');
       }
       return builder.toString();
    }
}
```